# New Facebook SDK (5.2.1) with Unity 4.3 Error on start

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I downloaded and installed the new Facebook SDK (5.2.1) into my game, and when I go to run it, I get this error (prior to input the access token and everything).

```
ArgumentException: Invalid generic arguments
Parameter name: typeArguments
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.MakeGenericMethod (System.Type[] methodInstantiation) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/monoAndRuntimeClassLibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:394)
FB+RemoteFacebookLoader+<LoadFacebookClass>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:435)
```

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Did you managed to fix this issue? I am after the same problem. Since you posted a different questions on facebook and unity three days later, I would assume you figured that out.

Comment: No sorry, I did not. I went back to using the prior version (5.1). After a few days, went again to the download page and saw that 5.2.1 is not there anymore, so yea, probably has a lot of bugs.